# How to design a DB table with multiple DTOs

Tags: java, database, postgresql, database-design, dto

I have two `DTOs`:

```
RedCatDTO {
 color: string,
 someSpecialAttribute: string
}
```

and

```
BlueCatDTO {
 color: string,
 someSpecialAttribute: string
}
```

How can I design a Database table and store these two `DTOs`?

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Added an additional tag and improved the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE CAT {
 color varchar(24),
 attribute varchar(24),
}
```

JAVA

```
public class Cat{
  String color;
  String attribute;
}
public class BlueCat extends Cat{
  String color = blue;
}
```

Or you can just say

```
Cat blueCat = new Cat();
blueCat.setColor("blue");
```

Please note this is rough code, so you will need to investigate how to create table, etc.